# Azure database for postgreSQL Flexible Server and Entity Framework Core shows accented spanish words incorrectly

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-database-postgresql

I have created a Flexible Server (Azure database for postgreSQL), I am using pgadmin to connect to this database (Encoding UTF8), I have a table named skills, and using pgadmin shows the spanish words correctly.

- SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;
  UTF8
- SHOW CLIENT_ENCODING;
  SQL_ASCII

[image]

The problem is when I connect entity framework core to this database, shows accented spanish words incorrectly, for example:

- Publicación (Correct)
- Publicaci\xf3n (Incorrect)

When I send data from Web API to database it is inserted this way

- PublicaciÃ³n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option in Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server is Server Parameters,

Inside there is a parameter:

client_encoding was SQL_ASCII and I changed to UTF8

[image]

then my pgadmin shows accented spanish words correctly, that was the solution